# Getting Rails to work with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm trying to get Rails to work with Apache. To my supreme frustration, many of the instructions I've found for doing this are wildly divergent from one another. I tried following a few of them with no success.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, Rails 3.0.3 and Apache 2.2.16. I've already installed passenger. I don't really know what to do next.

Can anyone help me out, or at least give me a link to a decent, up-to-date set of instructions?

Comment: i tried that. Gave up and used nginx. I had my heart set on apache as well but nginx hasn't disappointed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try phusion_passenger. I had success with that.

Simple version `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger`. More options on the [official installation guide](http://www.modrails.com/install.html)

Edit acc. to comment about wrong installation line.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thanks. Just to be sure, you mean `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger` and not `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger1`, right?

Comment: That seemed to work. How do I test it? When I was using Mongrel, I would go to `mysite.com:3000/route` and it would work. If I would go to `mysite.com/route`, it wouldn't work, not surprisingly. Now, with Apache supposedly able to handle Rails apps, `mysite.com/route` still doesn't work (nor does `mysite.com:3000/route`, of course).

Comment: When you installed Passenger, it should have had instructions and code to paste into your Apache config file.

Comment: Right. I did that and I restarted Apache. What next? Is `mysite.com/route` just supposed to work at that point?

Comment: You are providing a little too meagre information. You did all that it says in the installation guide? And found it did not work? A bug maybe? Error logs? Errors? What configuration details did *you* choose?

Answer (score 2):

This [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development) should make it a breeze.

Comment: that didn't help me when I did it. I gave up and used nginx. Did you try out the setup that the OP has described?

Answer (score 1):

[Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/sitemap) has some lovely simple guides for setting things up.